# Python numpy array difference or summation giving wrong results

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, numpy

Here is the code

```
import numpy as np

class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
    def move(self, dx):
        self.x += dx

a = Test(x = np.array([6371000.0, 0.0, 0.0])
loc1 = a.x
print loc1
a.move(np.array([-9.81, 0.0, 0.0]))
loc2 = a.x
print loc2
print loc1[0] - loc2[0]
```

When I run this code (python 2.7), I am getting :

[ 6371000.    0.    0.]

[6370990.19    0.    0.]

0.0

Comment: What do you expect? You are subtracting the same number from itself!

Comment: I think both `loc1` and `loc2` is referencing the same array here (which is `a.x`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because Python uses references to numpy arrays.

In this line you set `loc1` to point at `a.x`

```
loc1 = a.x
```

and then `loc2` to point at the same array.

```
loc2 = a.x
```

That's why the difference is 0.0.

If you want to make a copy of the array, then you could simply muliply it with 1.0.

```
loc1 = a.x * 1.0
```

Comment: Thank you Petersen. Got it.